# Rounding to a specific number ex: 4 ,5, 9 ,0 sql

Tags: sql, rounding

I have prices that are going to be converted from one currency to several other currencies but once they are converted I would like to round them to a specific number.

The examples on what I need to round are the following :

Anything under 10 round to the next digit. For this I can just use the CEILING function.
Anything between 10-14 needs to rounded to 14.00. ex: 12.78 to 14.00
Between 14.01 and 15 needs to rounded to 15.00. ex: 14.25 to 15.00 
Between 15.01 and 19 needs to be rounded to 19.00 ex: 17.35 to 19.00
Between 19.01 and 20 needs to rounded to 20.00. ex: 19.25 to 20.00

I know this seems a little weird but it is a specification I've been given for my project. To round to the next multiple of 5 I also understand but it is the 4 and 9 values that are really stumping me.

What formula would I need to use to obtain these numbers, or would it be easier to explode the number, grab the value before the decimal and do a case based on the criteria I stated above?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is 20 the final case, or do the rules go up to 99?

Comment: You can use [modulo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) to identify numbers that are within 1 of a multiple of 5.  Then you can have just 2 cases - x mod 5 <= 4, and x mod 5 > 4.

Comment: 20 is not the final case, it goes up to 99. I need to be able to cover any case possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A case seems to make the most sense but your "rounding" logic may look a little strange:

```
CASE 
WHEN value < 10  THEN CEILING(value) 
WHEN value <= 14 THEN 14 
WHEN value <= 15  THEN 15 
WHEN value <= 19  THEN 19
WHEN value <= 20  THEN 20
END
```

Or you could convert from `float`s to `int`s and use the modulus (`%`) operator:

```
CASE 
WHEN value < 10  THEN CONVERT(int,CEILING(value)) 
WHEN CONVERT(int,CEILING(value)) % 5 = 0  -- 9.01 - 10, 14.01 - 15, 19.01 - 20, etc.
    THEN CONVERT(int,CEILING(value)) 
WHEN CONVERT(int,CEILING(value)) % 5 <= 4  -- 10.01 - 14, 15.01 - 19, etc.
    THEN CONVERT(int,FLOOR(value / 5)) * 5 + 4 
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have slightly odd requirements (there is no simple formula to cover all your cases), then I think your best bet is to use a [CASE...WHEN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement like this. Obviously tweak the precise inequalities based on your requirements:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN colVal < 10 THEN CEILING(colVal)
            WHEN colVal <= 14 THEN 14
            WHEN colVal <= 15 THEN 15
            WHEN colVal <= 19 THEN 19
            WHEN colVal <= 20 THEN 20
            ELSE someotherval
       END
```

EDIT: Based on the clarified requirements, D Stanley's answer with the modulo stuff is a better fit.